# UITableViewCell with add photo button like in Contacts app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

How can I create UITableViewCell with add photo button like in Contacts app?

```
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 1, 70, 40)] autorelease];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 217, 30)];
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding photo to tableviewcell is not too complicated.

```
UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,40,30)];

[btn setBackGoundImage:[UIImage imageName:@"ABC.png"]];

[cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
```

If you want your application looks similar to contacts app as in Iphone, then you need to use  scrollview instead of tableview.

Answer (score 0):

just add a UIButton and set a thumb picture to its backgroundimage or imageview property.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make a custom subclass of UITableViewCell with a xib. Then you will just  have to pick your cells in the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like this

`myCustomCell *cell =
(myCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

and then configure them

Comment: I already do that with:

UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 1, 70, 40)] autorelease];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 217, 30)];
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

Comment: I would like to know the way how can i add this UIButton like that

Comment: You will have to do the same, add a UIButton to your code and use `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` and then you will have to implement `-buttonPressed`

Comment: Did you see photo  i.stack.imgur.com/nrOt8.png
I would like that the button being outside of UITableViewCell

Comment: Yes ok, but there is no tableViewCell and no tableView. It s just a common UIView in my opinion. But if you want to add subviews (uibutton is a uiview) you can still do the same

Comment: so do you think it's just a UIImage in the background?

Comment: the "Ajouter une photo" View is a UIButton (this is a subclass of UIView, so you will be able to use `[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];`. You will have to set the frame of this View (as you did previously for your label), the UIButtonStyle, the title and the selector (as I said 2 post earlier, it's the function that will be call when you click on the button). You can also set a background to this button. Did I miss something ? Maybe I didn't really understand what you are really trying to do !

Comment: I would like add a UIButton next to The cells and not inside the cell